# What is the easiest way to prove that $|e^{At}v| \leq K e^{\sigma t}|v|$ whenever $v$ is in the stable subspace of $A$?

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, matrix-calculus

I am teaching a class in dynamical systems and I am looking for a quick proof that if a vector $v$ is in the stable subspace of a matrix $A$ and all negative eigenvalues of $A$ satisfy $\Re \lambda < - \sigma < 0$, then there is a number $K$, such that $|e^{At}v| \leq K e^{-\sigma t}|v|$.

One way to do this would be by using Jordan Canonical Form and changes of variables, another would be by proving this inequality for diagonalizable matrices and applying a density argument. I am looking for something shorter, which ideally wouldn't require Jordan Canonical Form or real analysis concepts like density.

Comment: You can reduce the problem, as the stable invariant subspace of $A$ is still stable for $\tilde A=A+σI$. Thus it is sufficient that $e^{\tilde At}v$ is bounded.

Comment: @LutzLehmann that worked, thank you!